# Cron bash script - find command never execuced

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Please look at my script to grab and parse xmltv data:

```
#! /bin/bash

/bin/rm -f /home/hts/webgrab/multiple/out/*.xml

/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/1/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/2/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/3/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/4/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/5/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/6/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/7/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/8/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/9/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/10/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/11/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/12/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/13/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/14/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/15/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/16/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/17/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/18/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/19/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/20/run.sh &
/home/hts/webgrab/multiple/21/run.sh &


wait

/usr/bin/tv_cat /home/hts/webgrab/multiple/out/*.* > /home/hts/webgrab/multiple/out/guide.xml

#copy result with timestamp
/bin/cp -rf /home/hts/webgrab/multiple/out/guide.xml "/var/www/guide/guide-$(date +"%Y%m%d").xml"

sleep 10

#find and rename file 5 day old
/usr/bin/find /var/www/guide -type f -name 'guide*' -mtime 5 -execdir /bin/mv {} /var/www/guide/pl.xml ';' 2> /home/hts/epg.log
```

As you can see, multiple `webgrab` program instances are executed, script waits for all of them to finish. Then, results are joined into single xmltv file (guide.xml), then guide.xml copied to `/var/www/guide` directory with timestamp. Last step:

`/usr/bin/find /var/www/guide -type f -name 'guide*' -mtime 5 -execdir /bin/mv {} /var/www/guide/pl.xml ';' 2> /home/hts/epg.log`

finds old file from 5 days ago  -if exsists (`-mtime 5`) and renames it (with overwrite old one) to `pl.xml`.

Problem: it looks like last command is never executed. As a my cron job result, I'm getting only new timestamp file, but renamed `pl.xml` is always missing. But if I run `find` command as above from command line, old file is renamed correctly to `pl.xml`

Any ideas what's wrong here? Full command paths are included to make sure they will run with cron. But it did not help, find and rename command does not work. Old file exists for sure, because it has been created 5 days earlier, but from some reason, rename command does not work from cron inside this script.

Comment: What do you see in `/home/hts/epg.log`? Does your `cron` user have write access there?

Comment: try `set -x` at the top of your script.

Comment: Strange if I moved `find` as first command to execute in my script, it seems to be working. But I still don't understand why placed as last not working

Comment: Well, still does not work. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work. I added that as single cron job - results are the same. Any ideas?

Comment: What do your logs say, as asked by tripleee and abihaora? I also would add the `-v` option to `mv` and not only redirect stderr to epg.log, but stdout as well. Also, you `-mitime` is suspicious. Maybe there are no files starting with _guide_, which had been modified more than 120 hours ago? For the safe side, run a `find` command before that which just displays the modification time of all _guide_-files.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong, `find` command is the culprit - `-mtime 5` options indeed returns files 5 days old. However, it also takes care to time, not only date. So, as long as that's not full 5 days ago (including hour of day), `find` won't return anything. My possible solutions:

- make sure I call `find` at spefic time to get always full 5 days
- don't use `mtime` and parse timestamps from filenames instead (that seems to be
  simplest and most safe solution)
- find some way to force `find`command to ommit hours and use date only for its calculations (I actually have no idea how to do that)